# How to get index.android.js and index.ios.js files in fresh react-native application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in react-native world!

I have seen many tutorials on react-native. In all the tutorials they say that we should run this command to create a new app called myApp:

```
react-native init myApp
```

So, I have done the same thing. Now, when I see the files that are automatically generated, I see a difference between tutorials and my code.

In my code, I get an `index.js` file.

But the tutorials that I follow, I can see `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` files.

I also want to have these two different files as I will develop different UI's for Android and iOS.

Comment: Just create them. You can create any component later with this pattern `xxxx.ios.js` `xxx.android.js` and they will load base on platform.

Comment: @TarasDanylyuk so, you mean that I can create a common application for both platforms and then if I need a screen different on both platform, that time I should just create a copy of that component and just rename both files to xxx.android.js and xxx.ios.js and that's it!!

Comment: @TarasDanylyuk If I am getting it wrong then can you please explain it with a small example?

Comment: Yes you can have same file for both platform, but if you want to have different buttons on each platform, you just create `Button.ios.js` and `Button.android.js`. Then when importing this component you are using `import Button from './Button'` and you will have them different on each platform. Consider reading official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions

Comment: @Thanks Now, I got it clear.